# SQLException: invalid cursor state

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee, glassfish, derby

Why am I getting a `SQLException` with my query?

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT note FROM NOTES4EME WHERE id=?");
stmt.setString(1,"1");
ResultSet a = stmt.executeQuery();
return a.getInt(1);
```

What am I missing?

I have a method :

```
public int afficheNote(int id) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");

        String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TLdb;create=true;user=root;password=root";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        String query = "SELECT NOTES FROM NOTES4EME WHERE ID = '" + id + "'";

        //PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);


        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT note FROM NOTES4EME WHERE id=?");
        stmt.setString(1,"1");
        ResultSet a = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (a.next()) {
        return a.getInt(1);
        }
        return -1;

    }
```

and I call this method in a .JSP :

```
<% 
  int a = mybean.afficheNote(1);
%>
```

Comment: Full stack trace of the exception ?

Answer (score 0):

Call `next` before invoking `getInt`

```
ResultSet a = stmt.executeQuery();

if (a.next()) {
   return a.getInt(1);
} else {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Nothing found for 1...");
}
```

Comment: I tried and it's giving me this :

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource

Comment: I suspect that is happening in a different part of the code. Update your question with the full details...

Answer (score 0):

The [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) Javadoc says (in part) *initially the cursor is positioned before the first row.* So you need to call `next`. Add something like

```
if (a.next()) {
    return a.getInt(1);
}
return -1;
```